# Alpha Over makes my image brighter

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes

So i've been sitting here with a problem in blender 2.9 that i just can't seem to solve, when i add an alpha over with id mask and more to make a certain material glow, the image gets brighter (more noticeable with a darker background), the brighter result just removes the rather grimmier atmosphere in my opinion, but the brighter result seems to get caused by alpha over node. The top image is the composited result and the bottom image is the render result. What i've tried so far is looking at other topics, like adding an alpha convert node, but this just seems to disable every composite node i added. I tried replacing the Alpha Over with an add node but this just seems to have the same effect.

[image: Compositor nodes]
[image: Composited result]
[image: Render result]

Comment: Try hooking different earlier nodes directly to the viewer, one at a time, to make sure you are getting the expected result from each one. [subject-relevant non-offensive pun here]

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard I will try!